# File "pyarrow/lib.pyx", line 35, in init pyarrow.lib ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Tags: python, numpy, pyarrow

I'm trying out StreamLit for the first time and upon running my program I get this error

```
File "pyarrow/lib.pyx", line 35, in init pyarrow.lib ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I understand this could be due to a numpy version error but when I try importing numpy.core.multiarray in my script I get no errors.
How would I solve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some details about your (python) environment and how you installed pyarrow?

Comment: @joris PyArrow was installed when I install streamline. My vent is a typical mini forge python 3.8.6 environment.

Comment: Can you show the output of `conda list` then?

Comment: @joris It's pretty long but https://pastebin.pl/view/3d6dd666

Comment: You could try to install pyarrow with conda instead of with pip?

Comment: Thanks!!! Taking inspiration off your comment I reinstalled with Conda and it worked.